# How can i load a static image from a jQuery function for a spring boot application

Tags: jquery, html, spring-boot

I have added my image in `src/main/resources/static/images/myimage`.

If I provide the below in my html directly, **then the image is loaded**:

```
<div id="testing"> 
    <div class="card-post__image" 
         style="background-image: url('images/myimages/default-user-imge.jpeg');">
    </div>
</div>
```

But if append these html code using jQuery, then the image is not loaded. Is it because that the image is under the `static` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `background-image` with `url` path, you need to provide these properties: *width, height* and *background-size*

```js
$('.card-post__image')
    .css('background-image', 'url("https://www.zamzar.com/images/filetypes/jpg.png")')
    .css({ width: '100px', height: '100px', 'background-size': '100%' });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="testing"> 
    <div class="card-post__image"></div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to check an image is ready to use or not, you can use `Image` class:

```js
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function () {
  $('body').append(this);
};

image.error = function () {
  console.log('ERROR!');
};

image.src = 'https://www.zamzar.com/images/filetypes/jpg.png';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```